# Cloudflare not respecting edge cache TTL value

Tags: http, cloudflare

### Scenario

I have a domain `static.example.com`. All resources under that domain are write-once, read-many. I want Cloudflare to cache its resources as aggressively as possible; if a resource ever changes on the server, the only means by which a client should be able to fetch the updated version is if I manually go into Cloudflare and clear the cache for that resource.

Now, I understand that this is not possible. The next best thing I can do to make this happen on the server (**not** with client-side caching e.g. with `Cache-Control` headers) is set the edge cache TTL as high as possible.

### The problem

I have configured a Page Rule in Cloudflare as follows:

```
*static.example.com/*
Cache Level: Cache Everything, Edge Cache TTL: a month
```

However, Cloudflare does not seem to be respecting the edge cache TTL of one month.

### Reproduction steps

#### Actual behavior

1. `GET https://static.example.com/img.png`. Response header `cf-cache-status: MISS`. Load is slow, since it goes to my origin server.
2. `GET https://static.example.com/img.png`, from the same IP. Response header `cf-cache-status: HIT`. Load is fast, since it is cached by Cloudflare.
3. Wait one day, during which I do not make any additional requests to `static.example.com`.
4. `GET https://static.example.com/img.png`, from the same IP. **Response header `cf-cache-status: MISS`. Load is slow! (Why wasn't the edge cache TTL of one month respected? The resource should not have been purged from the Cloudflare cache!)**

#### Expected behavior

1. `GET https://static.example.com/img.png`. Response header `cf-cache-status: MISS`. Load is slow, since it goes to my origin server.
2. `GET https://static.example.com/img.png`, from the same IP. Response header `cf-cache-status: HIT`. Load is fast, since it is cached by Cloudflare.
3. Wait one day, during which I do not make any additional requests to `static.example.com`.
4. `GET https://static.example.com/img.png`, from the same IP. **Response header `cf-cache-status: HIT`. Load is fast.**

### Question

Why is the edge cache TTL value I set not respected by Cloudflare's proxy servers?

Comment: Please submit the headers from your console.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a cache. Expiration is just advice on when to definitely expire it, but like with all caches - you can not trust anything to be cached - or to be cached for the whole period. The item is most likely expired from their cache with last recently used logic, and any content that is popular will push your image out of the cache. If you want a guarantee for elements being on a CDN, you should not use a proxy based CDN like Cloudflare is.